# How do you wrap up a BOOL for KVC in Cocoa/Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, key-value-coding

I'm using KVC to iterating through a few views. Having trouble setting BOOL properties:

```
[self setValue:YES forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myView%d.userInteractionEnabled", n]];
```

I get: *warning: passing argument 1 of 'setValue:forKeyPath:' makes pointer from integer without a cast.*

There is no [NSValue valueWithBool:YES] or similar that I can find.

What to do?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The compiler is generating a warning because the first argument of `-setValue:forKeyPath:` expects and object. YES is not an object.

The answer is right there in "NSValue.h":

`[NSNumber numberWithBool: aBool]`

Later versions of Xcode allow you to use the literal syntax:

`[foo setValue:@YES forKey:@"bar"]`

Answer (score 1):

You also can use Literal expression 
@(YES)

For More Info 
[llvm Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)